# CSS scrolling div

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

Is there anyway I can make the scrolling green div push the black navigation up the page rather than scroll over the top of it?

Here is my example, scroll down the page and the banner will fade and scroll:

http://www.mharrisweb.co.uk/

Jquery added:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  function scrollBanner() {
    //Get the scoll position of the page
    scrollPos = jQuery(this).scrollTop();

    //Scroll and fade out the banner text
    jQuery('.hero-unit').css({
      'margin-top' : -(scrollPos/3)+"px",
      'opacity' : 1-(scrollPos/300)
    });

    //Scroll the background of the banner
    jQuery('.fade').css({
      'background-position' : 'center ' + (-scrollPos/8)+"px"
    });    
  }

  jQuery(window).scroll(function() {        
    scrollBanner();        
  });`
```

I would like the same effect as this site:

http://themetrust.com/demos/hero/

Comment: Your question miss some informations. It seems you use a jQuery plugin for parallax scrolling. Which it is? And can you give use some code chunks?

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the problem: http://www.mharrisweb.co.uk/ss.gif

My jquery is in the head of the page, buts its the CSS positioning thats the problem

Comment: Yes, I'v already seen the problem. But add informations to you question, about what plugin you are using, what code you have written. Nobody here will want to go through all <script> and <link> source files on your website to search for the problem.

Comment: Ahh OK

`jQuery(function($) {

  function scrollBanner() {
    //Get the scoll position of the page
    scrollPos = jQuery(this).scrollTop();

    //Scroll and fade out the banner text
    jQuery('.hero-unit').css({
      'margin-top' : -(scrollPos/3)+"px",
      'opacity' : 1-(scrollPos/300)
    });

    //Scroll the background of the banner
    jQuery('.fade').css({
      'background-position' : 'center ' + (-scrollPos/8)+"px"
    });    
  }
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {        
         scrollBanner();        

    });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can add the `div.navbar-fixed-top` to scroll behavior too ? With `.hero-unit`. So they'll move at the same "rate"

Comment: Thanks very much, I never though of that great idea